# reading manifest file from inside a war file produces error in tomcat 7

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat7, war, tomcat8

I built a web application on my windows 7 system with IntelliJ Idea an run it in a Tomcat 8.0. The web appliaction reads the manifest file correct and shows the right properties. On my webserver which runs on Ubuntu 14 and Tomcat 7 however there is a strange exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert Build-Name of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.jar.Attributes$Name
at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:419)
at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:46)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:469)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:172)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2414)
at net.bootsfaces.render.RBadge.encBegin(RBadge.java:46)
at net.bootsfaces.component.Badge.encodeBegin(Badge.java:63)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView(RewriteViewHandler.java:186)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:41)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:268)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:193)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My el-code in the *.xhtml file:

```
#{cic.manifest.mainAttributes.getValue('Build-Name')}
```

My java-bean-code (I think, I used it from stackoverflow, but did not find the source after looking for it again):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "cic")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationInformationController {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ConfigurationInformationController.class.getName());
    private Manifest manifest = null;
    public Manifest getManifest() {
        return manifest;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        File manifestFile = null;
        try {
            String home = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");
            manifestFile = new File(home, "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
            manifest = new Manifest();
            manifest.read(new FileInputStream(manifestFile));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to read the Manifest file from '"+manifestFile.getAbsolutePath()+"'",ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

I first thought it my be the servlet 3.0 and 3.1 specification difference, but I found nothing concerning the specification and my problem. I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention I used the getValue()-method from the manifest class. This method has two possible parameter inputs: getValue(Name name) and getValue(String name). However it apparently uses the getValue(Name name)-method instead of getValue(String name).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
#{cic.manifest.mainAttributes.get('Build-Name')}
```

There are two `getValue()` methods defined on [`Attributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/Attributes.html) objects, one that takes a `String` parameter and one that takes a `Attributes.Name` parameter. Looks like the EL implementation gets confused by this as it is trying to cast your string to an `Attributes.Name` object.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work. The error message is gone, but so is the manifest information.

Comment: Could you try adding a `.toString()` at the end, i.e. `#{cic.manifest.mainAttributes.get('Build-Name').toString()}`?

Comment: `#{cic.manifest.mainAttributes.get('Build-Name').toString()}` didn't work either. The error message and the manifest information are still both gone.

Comment: OK, last try before I delete my answer. Try dollar instead of hash: `${cic.manifest.mainAttributes.get('Build-Name')}`

Comment: I know I said last try, but here's one more: `#{cic.manifest.mainAttributes['Build-Name']}`

Comment: I added a method in my java-bean: `public String getAttributeValue(String key){
        Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
        return attributes.getValue(key);
    }` but this method still gives me no manifest information. I tried your suggestions as well, but the manifest data is still not found. On my local machine only getValue works. But not on my webserver. Nevertheless thank you for your help and the suggestion that el might confuse the getValue methods.